# Unable to load client print control - Seperate SQL server and Web server

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, printing, activex

I have a seperate SQL(2008 R2) box and web server(IIS 7). 
The IIS server is visible to the public the SQL box is not (as it should be)
On the web server there is a asp.net page with a report viewer control. 
The reportview control picks up a report from Reporting Services on the SQL box and displays the report in the web page. But when I try to print I get the  "Unable to load client print control" error message. 
I've  looked over all the many posts, and there are many, and have tried some of the "fixes" like updating with all the service packs, etc..

I can not have the end users adjust their security settings (this would number about 100,000 users)
There must be a definitive answer to this problem. I can not believe that MS would leave this so unusable.

Any suggestions or ideas?

TIA
John

***New information *****
I am able to log onto the web server and using IE on the Web server bring up the reportmanager on the SQL server and print successfully. I actually was able to see the print client download and I got the expected security prompts.

I tried bringing up the website in question the same way, i.e. using IE on the web server itself, the reports display but when I go to print I get the "Unable to load" error. This occurs on a machine that seconds before was able to download the activex and successfully print.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say is you normally have to be a local admin on the machine to actually install the client print control, if they are'nt then i think they will get this error.

I did see an issue a while ago where the ActiveX killbits update broke the client print control, i have a feeling this was on 2005 but it might be worth checking?